# Change input value attribute from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I do apologise if this question has been asked but after hours of searching I could not find a solution.

I have a snippet of JavaScript that allows a block of text to be hidden until the user clicks the read more button.

the problem is I need to change the input value attribute after click to read less than to read more after collapse.

JavaScript:

```js
function toggleMe(a){
var e=document.getElementById(a);
if(!e)return true;
if(e.style.display=="none"){
e.style.display="block"
document.getElementsById("toggle").value = "Read Less"
}
else{
e.style.display="none"
document.getElementsById("toggle").value = "Read More"
}
return true;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<div id="Read" style="display:none">
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
 </div>
<br />
 <input id="toggle" type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('Read')" value="Read More">
 <br />
```

as you can see from snippet above I am running into a problem where I don't know  properly what to change the value="" attribute.

Comment: you need to use `getElementById()`, not `getElementsById()` (remove the "s")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a typo:

```
document.getElementsById()
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById()
```

[Docs here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

When your javascript code doens't works, its a best practice to take a look on your console before anything:

[image]

In your case, that is the exception thrown. If you click the right link `js:25` it would point straight to the `getElementsById` function.

Comment: thankyou very much... must have been lack of sleep :D

Answer (score 1):

```js
function toggleMe(a){
    var e=document.getElementById(a);
    if(!e)return true;
    if(e.style.display=="none"){
        e.style.display="block"
        document.getElementById("toggle").value = "Read Less"
    } else{
        e.style.display="none"
        document.getElementById("toggle").value = "Read More"
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<div id="Read" style="display:none">
  <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
</div>
<br />
<input id="toggle" type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('Read')" value="Read More">
<br />
```

Comment: What @DontVoteMeDown is saying (sarcastically) is that just putting fixed code without any explanation of what you've done is not really helping anybody.  It's not explaining to the OP what they've done wrong, and it means people have to read/compare every single line to see what you've actually changed to fix it

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, I know your answer is better (did I write somewhere something else?) but do you think it's worth to write comment like this? does it give plus to anything?

Comment: @freefaller, yes you are right and in this case people can decide if they want to compare them or not but they can try out the running code

Comment: Sorry @harcos, I disagree.  I think in its current state your answer is not really helpful, as it involves people having to work to see what your answer actually is

Comment: Your answer adds less than my comment, actually. You could improve it, but you didn't event after my comment.

Comment: To be fair @DontVoteMeDown - your comment was pretty sarcastic, and not everybody gets/understand sarcasm.  It's not necessarily obvious that you were suggesting that they provide an explanation.  That doesn't take away from the fact that you were right

Comment: ok, thanks for the helping comments, guys, I got your problem, I think it's taste of matter

Comment: @freefaller I know, that was my bad. I removed it.

Comment: @freefaller, "not really helpful" <> not useful

Comment: Why do you argue with another person who tried to help, practiacally in the same time. You explained, but he gave a full working code. Some prefer the first some the second.

Comment: @harcos - that's a fair point, and you're right - your answer does work, even if it you don't help people with WHY it works.  I am unable to remove my downvote due to the time that has passed since I did it... if you make an edit that gives at least SOME explanation, I will remove it

Comment: @Laszlo, because answering a question is a multitude of things - it should not just providing the fixed code, but explaining why the fix works, making them understand so they don't do it again the future.  DontVoteMeDown's answer does exactly that - and even goes as far as to show the user how they could have found the fault themselves.  SO is not supposed to be a site to get a quick fix... it is a resource to allow people to find answers to their issues far into the future

Comment: I've spent enough time here - @harcos, if you edit, notify me and I'll remove the downvote

Comment: @freefaller, it's your right to downvote I just said I think it was unfair but it's up to you. I do it for helping and not for points so I'm sorry I won't edit just in order to let you undone the downvote.

Comment: Not a problem @harcos - we'll agree to disagree :-)